# Create custom Helper in ASP NET MVC 3 and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a helper with ASP NET MVC 3 and Razor to display my grid

```
@helper ListaPessoa(IEnumerable<TesteHelpersMV3.Models.PessoaModel> listaPessoa) 
{    
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Endereco</th>
        <th>DataNascimento</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in listaPessoa)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Nome }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Nome }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Nome })
            </td>
            <td>@item.Nome</td>
            <td>@item.Endereco</td>
            <td>@item.Cidade</td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
}
```

but the Razor can not find @Html.ActionLink and the following error occurs

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

what is wrong? ?? how to solve this problem??

Thank You

Leandro Prado

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `@using System.Web.Mvc.Html`.

This is [added automatically](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-3-razor-and-mvc.html) in Views\Web.config, so it won't apply to any pages outside of the Views folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use MVC helpers in App_Code.   You can still use WebPages helpers.

Comment: OK, but how to create my helper??

Comment: @Leandro: You can do something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710853/using-mvc-htmlhelper-extensions-from-razor-declarative-views

Comment: @SLaks Thank you this saved my bacon. My deploy script excluded *.config when copying the website to the server....

Comment: I was using a page outside the Views folder and got this error, which disappeared after adding the @using directive. I'll try and figure if I can also change web.config to fix it; just as an exercise. Bookmarked slaks blog. Thanks.