# Custom HTML Helpers in Razor & HTML Extension Methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

There are a lot of questions, here and everywhere, regarding the impossibility of using HtmlHelper extension methods (like ActionLink) in an @helper (razor) method.
Right now, in my project, I solved the problem passing as an extra parameter the current page (System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage page) to the @helper, like in

```
@helper HelperFunction(SampleParameter sp, System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage page)
```

and using it (trivially) as in

```
{
    ...
    @page.Html.ActionLink("Title", "Action")
    ...
}
```

I would like to know if it's too stupid :-), and why. It would be better, of course, to have direct access to the current HtmlHelper of the page where the @helper is called, but, anyway... if this a good solution...

Andrea

Comment: You're talking about **static** helpers in `App_Code`.

Comment: Yes, of course: which other method can exist, to create custom helpers in Razor?

Comment: There can be helper directly in the view :)

Comment: ah, ok, but that wouldn't be of much reuse...

Answer (score 1):

I was curious why this didn't work, so I had a little look.

When you put code into the App_Code folder, it inherits from `System.Web.WebPages.HelperPage` and although this has a `Html` property, it's a `System.Web.WebPages.HtmlHelper` and not a `System.Web.Mc.HtmlHelper`, which is why you can't find things like ActionLink on it :(

I had a quick look around, and [found this answer from Andrew Nurse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710853/using-mvc-htmlhelper-extensions-from-razor-declarative-views/4716933#4716933):

> Omar's got the right answer here, but
>   I wanted to add something (do feel
>   free to mark Omar's response as the
>   answer).
>
> We were aware of this in v1 and
>   weren't able to get a great fix in the
>   product, but David Ebbo (an architect
>   on the ASP.Net team) posted a sample
>   of a Visual Studio Code Generator that
>   is basically a first exploration of
>   the kind of ideas we're looking at to
>   make this work properly:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/10/27/turn-your-razor-helpers-into-reusable-libraries.aspx
>
> Try that out and see what you think!
>   Let David know if you have comments by
>   posting on his blog.

Unfortunately, it looks like you can't even put the Helper outside of App_Code into your Layout class or _ViewStart :(