# Action Image Link on MVC3 Razor using Helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How to do it with razor helper method?

The answer at question linked below uses extension method.
[Action Image MVC3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896439/action-image-mvc3-razor)

Comment: I have just Googled it! I don't know where to start. This solution can't be just copied in helper method because of varius dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why an extension method isn't suitable, but something like this should work:

```
@helper ActionImage(string action, object routeValues, string imagePath, string alt) {
    <a href="@Url.Action(action, routeValues)">
        <img src="@Url.Content(imagePath)" alt="@alt">
    </a>
}
```

That is just off the top of my head, so your milage may vary. You should also be able to use the implementation provided in the question as a `@functions { }` block rather than an extension method as well.

Comment: Can't use @Url.Something, have to include something?

Comment: calling @System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action doesn't help

Comment: @Ante where are you defining this helper? in a view that inherits from `WebViewPage<T>` or in `App_Code`?

Comment: @Ante, that is a limitation of the framework that may or may not be addressed in MVC4 (I haven't checked yet). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710853/using-mvc-htmlhelper-extensions-from-razor-declarative-views) describes a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example of my image html helper

small article about Html helpers and how to intergrate it

http://www.sexyselect.net/blog/post/2011/08/16/Writing-a-Razor-MVC3-HTML-Helpers

example of another in html helpers
http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page:creating-custom-html-helpers

Sample Code

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Insights the traffic light image.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="html">The HTML.</param>
        /// <param name="trafficLight">The traffic light.</param>
        /// <returns>Image for the current traffic light. If not recognised writes name ot he light.</returns>
        public static MvcHtmlString InsightTrafficLightImage(this HtmlHelper html, TrafficLight trafficLight)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            string color = string.Empty;
            string hoverText = string.Empty;
            switch (trafficLight)
            {
                case TrafficLight.Amber:
                    {
                        color = "Yellow";
                        hoverText = "Work in progress";
                        break;
                    }
                case TrafficLight.Green:
                    {
                        color = "green";
                        hoverText = "Complete";
                        break;
                    }

                case TrafficLight.Red:
                    {
                        color = "red";
                        hoverText = "Not yet started";
                        break;
                    }
                case TrafficLight.Black:
                case TrafficLight.Unknown:
                default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(color))
            {
                TagBuilder img = new TagBuilder("img");
                img.MergeAttribute("src", string.Format("/Content/images/traffic_light_{0}.gif", color));
                img.MergeAttribute("alt", hoverText);
                img.MergeAttribute("title", hoverText);
                result.Append(img.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                result.Append(Enum.GetName(typeof(TrafficLight), trafficLight));
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
        }
```

Hope you find it helpfull

Comment: I'm trying to find solution for helper method.. the similar method is described in the quoted link but I doesn't use @helper method..