# WebPageContext.Current is null after installing VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

So i decided to try Visual Studio 2012 professional. After installing it and opening my MVC3 solution I get null reference exception at ((WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html; where WebPageContext.Current is null. Bad think is: even after checking out "clean" solution and opening it with Visual Studio 2010 I still get same exception while other project members don't. The place where exception occurs is featured in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710853/using-mvc-htmlhelper-extensions-from-razor-declarative-views). Code:

```
// Workaround - exposes the MVC HtmlHelper instead of the normal helper
public static new HtmlHelper<object> Html
{
    get { return ((WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html; }
}
```