# The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view-helpers

I have an MVC4 project that I am trying to create a helper for. I have added a folder called "App_Code", and in that folder I added a file called MyHelpers.cshtml. Here are the entire contents of that file:

```
@helper MakeButton(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string iconName, string classes) {
    <a href='@Url.Action(linkText,actionName,controllerName)' class="btn @classes">Primary link</a>
}
```

(I know there are some unused params, I'll get to those later after I get this fixed)

I "cleaned" and built the solution, no errors.

In the page that uses the helper, I added this code.

```
@MyHelpers.MakeButton("Back","CreateOffer","Merchant","","btn-primary")
```

When I attempt to run the project, I get the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the
>   current context

I can't seem to find the correct way to write this - what am I doing wrong? It seems to be correct as compared to examples I've seen on the web?

Comment: I think you need to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710853/using-mvc-htmlhelper-extensions-from-razor-declarative-views.

Comment: Did you mean to use `@Html.ActionLink` rather than `@Url.Action`? I've put a footnote in my answer about the two.

Answer (score 4):

As JeffB's link suggests, your helper file doesn't have access to the UrlHelper object.

This is an example fix:

```
@helper MakeButton(string linkText, string actionName,
    string controllerName, string iconName, string classes) {

    System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper urlHelper =
        new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
    <a href='@urlHelper.Action(linkText,actionName,controllerName)'
        class="btn @classes">Primary link</a>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For my helpers I create a base class:

```cs
using System.Web.WebPages;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class HelperBase : HelperPage
    {
        public static new HtmlHelper Html
        {
            get { return ((WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html; }
        }
        public static System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper Url
        {
            get { return ((WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Url; }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my helper I do (to use yours as an example):

```html
@inherits MyProject.HelperBase
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html

@helper MakeButton(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string iconName, string classes) {
    <a href='@Html.ActionLink(linkText,actionName,controllerName)' class="btn @classes">Primary link</a>
}
```

Also, are you sure you didn't mean to use `@Html.ActionLink` (via [`LinkExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)) instead of [`@Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)? The latter doesn't seem to have a `linkText, actionName, controllerName` overload, the former does?

Comment: Your base class is brilliant! Did exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Yep perfect, exactly what I was looking for!