# Referencing @Html.Actionlink in a custom helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I have a custom helper which needs to call Html.ActionLink

```
@helper GetLink(int id, string name)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(name, "Index", "MyController", new { id = id }, null);
}
```

It works perfectly on another page but within my custom helper (Called customhelpers.cshtml and located within the App_Code folder) I get the following error:

```
'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)' has some invalid arguments
```

This means it cannot find the Html.ActionLink class however I tried referencing the relevant namespace (@using System.Web.MVC.Html) but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Htmlhelpers are not accessible from the App_Code, but you can see a nice [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710853/using-mvc-htmlhelper-extensions-from-razor-declarative-views) here from Paul Stovell (also mentioned by [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor))

Comment: Thanks. Numerous references to it being fixed on the links you provided but no evidence of that so using the workaround for now.