# How to use HtmlHelper inside of another one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a question from you guys!
i decided to create an HmlHelper with some of HtmlHelrs inside of it and I create this Helper in Razor format, but when compiling the project I got an null reference Error which points to HtmlHelpers that I used inside .
so i dont know how can i solve this problem

see this View that i created :

```
 @helper LanguageCheckBoxes(string containerCssClass,string containerSpanCssClass,string checkboxParentCssClass,
    string name, string checkboxCssClass, IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> model)
{
    <div class="@containerCssClass">
    @Html.Label(@BMAIiCGS.Resources.Public.Labels.LanguageList, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
<span class="@containerSpanCssClass">
    @foreach (var item in model)
        {
        <span class="@checkboxParentCssClass">
            <input type="checkbox" name="@name" value="@item.Value" checked="@item.Selected" disabled="@item.Disabled" class="@checkboxCssClass" />
            @Html.Label(item.Text, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </span>

        }
</span>
</div>
}
```

and this is the Error which i cached :

[image]

I appreciate someone helps me

Comment: You should probably get rid of `@` prefix on `@BMAIiCGS.Resources.Public.Labels.LanguageList`.

Comment: Are you sure "@BMAIiCGS.Resources.Public.Labels.LanguageList" contains data?  Also, I cannot say that Html.Label(...) is what you want to use here.  <span class="col-md-3">@BMAIiCGS.Resources.Public.Labels.LanguageList</span> might work equally well.

Comment: @Eckert : Yup ! i'm sure this value is not Null and also I must add this notation that I used this html block in my main View before  and there was Not any Error before.so i think this can not lead to this Error.

Comment: try @BMAIiCGS.Resources.Public.Labels.LanguageList outside of the Label helper.  like: <span>@BMAIiCGS.Resources.Public.Labels.LanguageList</span>.  Does it still give you an error?

Comment: @Eckert : I did what you said but still i have same error. Note : I searched the web and i found the same problem on this link (ofcourse same error with MVC3 and I'm working on MVC5 ) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710853/using-mvc-htmlhelper-extensions-from-razor-declarative-views

Comment: but this also could NOT help me out

Comment: You should edit your OP and include the helper code.  If your helper does return data, it would show something, rather than giving a null exception error.

Comment: @Eckert : Excuse me budy! I didnt get what you mean by OP

Comment: OP = original post (your question post).  As in update your question to include your helper code.