# Having razor @helper in App_code folder using ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Where can I find tutorials on how exactly get this to work?

I am trying to have @helper in App_code directory of my MVC3 app, so far when I try to use them in other razor pages, they cannot be found.

Comment: Looks like your question was answered by SLaks - could you pelase mark it as such?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to call the helpers as static methods of the page name.

For example, if you have a helper named `HelpMe` in `App_Code/MyHelpers.cshtml`, you would write

```
@MyHelpers.HelpMe(...)
```

Comment: It might not be the "Areas" that are the problem. I can use the @MyHelper.Help() syntax just fine in a normal ASP.NET MVC project. But I'm trying to get it working in an Orchard module, implemented as a separate project. And in that separate project, which isn't itself a full Web app, the @MyHelper.Help() syntax works in the IDE, but at runtime it says, "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'MyHelper' does not exist in the current context." It doesn't seem to be picking up the files in the App_Code directory for compiling. Might be worth its own question.

Comment: Yes; you should ask a separate question.

Comment: Hi! I have created an idea in ASP.NET to make this more useful: [Support @helper ExtensionMethod(this HtmlHelper html) for views in APP_CODE](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3670180-support-helper-extensionmethod-this-htmlhelper-ht)... I know this is just a little bit of suggar, but it could make a lot for people trying to write html extension methods... Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Scott Gu just wrote a blog post about this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look at this SO question and associated answer:
[Razor: Declarative HTML helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451287/razor-declarative-html-helpers/4451843#4451843)

It does work, though I find that in the end, I usually opt for writing another extension method off of HtmlHelper.