# Declarative Helper Methods in Razor RTM

Tags: .net, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I saw Scott Guthrie's post about helper methods via [his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx).

Specifically this:

[image]

I see the bunch of RC version of MVC 3 posts about the lack of helper methods... I see the syntactical support for it (`@helper`) gets highlighted, but I have this in `/Views/Helpers/SomeHelper.cshtml` (defined as a partial view):

```
@helper SomeHelper(string text)
{
    if (text != null)
    {
        <text>
            @text
        </text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>
            Unknown
        </text> 
    }
}
```

I use it this way:

```
<div>
Helper with Text:
@SomeHelper("This is not null text.")
</div>
```

But I get SomeHelper is not defined.... so where did I mess this up?  Is there something I need to do to register these views as helpers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've done this by creating an `App_Code` folder in my project, then creating a `Helpers.cshtml` file in that folder.

Then, in an `.cshtml` view, use:

```
@Helpers.SomeHelper("This is not null text.")
```

This is the only way I've found to create shared declarative helper methods across the entire web project.  If there are others, I'd like to hear about them.

Comment: Correct, this is the only way this can work in MVC right now. In the future will have a better story for global helpers. We just didn't have the time to get this to work.

Comment: Even with the web application template?

Comment: @marcind What about ASP.NET MVC 4? Will there be others ways there to make global helpers?

Comment: Note that the standard @Html-Helper apparently doesn't work in App_Code, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451287/razor-declarative-html-helpers.