# Using @Html inside shared @helper in App_Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

I am building a very basic MVC3 site while I learn and I am having difficulty with the following declarative Razor html helper.

Inside RMB.cshtml inside App_Code folder:

```
@helper ReplaceCrLf(string strText)
{
    @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(strText).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
}
```

Inside my index.cshtml view:

```
@RMB.ReplaceCrLf(Model.Post)
```

This gives me a null reference exception on Html in the helper, because it doesn't seem to know what it is.  I can work around this by passing Html from the view to the helper, but I was wondering if there is another way for my shared html helpers to be able to reference Html without me having to pass it in to ever helper I write?

For completeness, here is the working workaround:

In RMB.cshtml in App_Code

```
@helper ReplaceCrLf(string strText, System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper Html)
{
    @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(strText).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
}
```

In index.cshtml view

```
@RMB.ReplaceCrLf(Model.Post, Html)
```

Comment: Based on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451287/razor-declarative-html-helpers/4453637#4453637), it is currently a limitation of putting custom Helpers in AppCode folder.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I add this to any .cshtml files in App_Code now.

```
// Using's are needed to ensure helpers function correctly.
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Routing;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Razor;
@functions {
    private static WebViewPage page { get { return PageContext.Page as WebViewPage; } } 
    private static System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic> html { get { return page.Html; } }
    private static UrlHelper url { get { return page.Url; } }
    private static dynamic viewBag { get { return page.ViewBag; } }
}
```

**EDIT: Have modified the helper variable names to lowercase as I have had some conflicts with the built-in helpers names. I have modified the HTML helper to be generic which allows the use of TextBoxFor etc helpers**

This makes those wonderful helpers available to all @helper methods and functions in the file.

Many thanks to [Neshta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26158532/1166163) for the original concept!

---

Complete Example to answer the question:

In RMB.cshtml in the App_Code folder

```
@functions {
    public static WebViewPage page = (PageContext.Page as WebViewPage);
    public static HtmlHelper<object> html = page.Html;
}

@helper ReplaceCrLf(string strText)
{
    @html.Raw(html.Encode(strText).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
}
```

In View:

```
@RMB.ReplaceCrLf("line1\nline2") // No passing HtmlHelper
```

Comment: @Omid-RH I've declined the edit as I believe I explicitly put this namespace on HtmlHelper  as there are conflicting classes with that name (From memory a generic and non-generic one) included by the prior using statements. If you can confirm this isn't the case you're welcome to propose the edit again and I will accept.

Answer (score 21):

I used a workaround like following

```
@helper HtmlRaw(string s)
{
    @(new HtmlString(s))
}

@helper ReplaceCrLf(string strText)
{
    @HtmlRaw(HttpUtility
                        .HtmlEncode(strText)
                        .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
}
```

Answer (score 16):

It is possible to get helpers from the PageContext:

```
var page = (WebViewPage) PageContext.Page;
var Url = page.Url;
var Html = page.Html;
var ViewBag = page.ViewBag;
// and so on
```

Usage (like standard helpers):

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home")
@Html.Raw("some encoded string")
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like helpers in App_Code work but you don't have access to standard MVC Html. helpers

see [Razor: Declarative HTML helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451287/razor-declarative-html-helpers)

Comment: Darn it, that also eventually took me to the original blog where I saw how to do this in the first place.  Here's looking forward to MVC4 then :(

Comment: Hi! I have created an idea in ASP.NET user voice related to this: [Support @helper ExtensionMethod(this HtmlHelper html) for views in APP_CODE](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3670180-support-helper-extensionmethod-this-htmlhelper-ht)... help is appreciated in making it come to the front-lines... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add second Parameter in your helper as bellow

```
@helper ReplaceCrLf(string strText,HtmlHelper<dynamic> html)
{
    @Html.Raw(html.Encode(strText).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"));
}
```

when you use this helper pass this.Html as second Parameter

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough:

```
var message = new HtmlString(toast.Message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
```

No need to use `Html.Raw().`

Comment: Confirmed, did it right in CSHTML <text>@(new HtmlString(ShortenedText))</text>