# How do I access a static Custom Helper in MVC from within a "Templated" @helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a custom helper method defined in a static class like so:

```
namespace MyProject.Helpers
{
    public static class MyHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString TestData(this HtmlHelper helper,    Guid controlId)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<div>Test Data: {0}</div>", controlId.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to use this helper within another helper that is defined as a cshtml template like so:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using MyProject.Helpers

@helper PanelHelper(ADOR.CMSWeb.Data.CMSControl control)
{
    <div>
    @Html.TestData(Guid.NewGuid())
    </div>
}
```

This does not work. I don't have access to the Html helper from within the cshtml helper. I've tried using System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, but my extension method isn't on that class.

Does anyone know how to access a static Helper from within a cshtml Helper to accomplish what I'm trying to do? It seems like it should be easy to do.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The "@Html" is not available from within the cshtml helper.

Comment: Why not just add another method to your static class for `PanelHelper`?. Really, you should avoid view helpers altogether. They violate the MVC pattern, aren't compiled until runtime (meaning your code blows up live instead of during build), and are difficult to test.

Comment: Here's a related question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679618/using-html-inside-shared-helper-in-app-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm personally not a fan of `@helper` for this and other reasons.  Changing your helper to a partial view would resolve the issue.

Another solution is to add `HtmlHelper` as another parameter to your `PanelHelper`.

Or you could create a `PanelHelper` extension method and use the [TagBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to create your Html.

(I would highly recommend using `TagBuilder` instead of `string.Format` to create Html.  It can create html in a stricter format and is [unit-tested my Microsoft](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/System.Web.WebPages.Test/Mvc/TagBuilderTest.cs))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used String.Format for this simple code to show that I was actually going to use the Guid value that I passed in. I'm using TagBuilder in my other helper.