# Issue with TextArea inside asp.net MVC 5 Html helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do a very simple Html helper in Asp.net MVC 5:

```
@helper GetMyTextArea()
{
    @Html.TextArea("myText")
}
```

Then i try to include it in my view: (the helper is in a file called `MyHelp.cshtml`, located in the `App_Code` Folder)

```
@MyHelp.GetMyTextArea()
```

If i render my view now, i get following exception:

> System.NullReferenceException:
>   System.Web.WebPages.HelperPage.Html.get returned null.

Anyone know this issue? I think i can work around it with a `partial view` but this shouldn't be a problem with a html helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain limitations apply when using `@helper` in `App_Code` folder, such like no direct access to standard `HtmlHelper` methods (you need to pass it manually by including it in your method, e.g. `@helper GetMyTextArea(HtmlHelper Html)`). You can add `@functions` which enables direct access to `HtmlHelper` methods:

```
@functions {
    public static WebViewPage page = (PageContext.Page as WebViewPage);
    public static HtmlHelper<object> html = page.Html;
}
```

Hence, `MyHelp.cshtml` content should be like this:

```
// adapted from /a/35269446/
@functions {
    public static WebViewPage page = (PageContext.Page as WebViewPage);
    public static HtmlHelper<object> html = page.Html;
}

@helper GetMyTextArea()
{
    @Html.TextArea("myText")
}
```

Afterwards, you can call the helper method in view page as `@MyHelp.GetMyTextArea()` without passing `HtmlHelper` manually.

Similar issues:

[Razor: Declarative HTML helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451287/razor-declarative-html-helpers)

[Using @Html inside shared @helper in App_Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679618/using-html-inside-shared-helper-in-app-code)