# Html.TextBoxFor overload which allows formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any Html.TextBoxFor overload implementation which allows value formatting?

I know about EditorFor and DataFormatString but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Use `EditorFor` and create an Editor Template.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is possible in ASP.NET MVC 4: http://forums.asp.net/p/1720963/4599128.aspx/1?Html+TextBoxFor+value+formatting

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. You should summarise the contents of that post in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an EditorTemplate? Of course, if you're going to use different ways of formatting the same objects you're going to have to use the template name in the call to `EditorFor()` (so it'll look like `EditorFor(object, "TemplateName")`.

Another option is to add your own HTML Helper. The MVC source code is open so you can download the RTM sources for 2/3 and look at how `Html.TextBoxFor()` is implemented.

I think `EditorFor()` is the correct solution to this problem. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: It causes some duplication. I have htmlAttributes set to new {@class="someClass"} for all my textboxes and I don't want to repeat it in all EditorTemplates

Comment: EditorTemplates should be the only place you need to add `someClass`. Keep 'em in there and all of your inline will be much cleaner.

Comment: I've done both approaches and the `EditorFor()` is cleaner. Writing HtmlHelper extensions works great but it takes more time and gets tricky (does your helper work with the new client side validation, etc).

Comment: I prefer to use Razor Declarative Helpers instead of Templates. And here I just need to format value for HtmlTextBoxFor.

Comment: I did a quick google on "razor declarative helpers" and it looks like this is per view, right? For one offs that seems fine but for reusable things that doesn't sound good. Or am I missing something? Reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451287/razor-declarative-html-helpers

Comment: @Cymen, you can put helper into App_Code folder and then it becomes visible globally

Comment: @Idsa: That is rather ugly. Hopefully that is fixed in MVC 4. I'll try that method too though. Thanks!