# Difference between Razor single statement and block

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Why does the first segment work and the second throw an "Invalid expression term '`<`' error at the label tag?

First segment:

```
@foreach( var f in new List<List<string>>{ new List<string>{ new List<string>{ "PumpSize", "Pump Size" },
new List<string>{ "PumpType", "Pump Type" }, 
new List<string>{ "WellHead", "Well Head" } } )
{
    <label>@f[1]
    </label>
}
```

Second segment:

```
@{
    var fields = new List<List<string>>{ new List<string>{ new List<string>{ "PumpSize", "Pump Size" },
        new List<string>{ "PumpType", "Pump Type" }, 
        new List<string>{ "WellHead", "Well Head" } };
    fields.ForEach( f => 
    {
        <label>@f[1]</label>
    } );
}
```

The error I get is with the `<label>`, "Invalid expression term '`<`'.

If it matters, my browser is IE9.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `ForEach` is a method that accepts a lambda expression, so, you cannot pass  a View (or a piece of html) code in this scope. I recommend you use a simple `foreach` loop.

```
@foreach(var field in fields) {
   <label>@field[1]</label>
}
```

If you have problems with this approach, you also can use the [`<text>`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx) razor tag.

```
@{

  foreach(var field in fields) {
    <text> 
       <label>@field[1]</label>
    </text>
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes the foreach works.  But, you are saying Razor does not understand how to handle a lambda expression?  It looks like you are correct, but do you know why?  I know it is not the same, but I see code like @Html...(x => x...) all over the place.

Comment: The reason is, you cannot pass a razor context to a lambda expression of a specifique type. Maybe you can create a Razor Helper Method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328303/how-to-pass-in-a-lambda-to-a-razor-helper-method