# VB.NET and MVC 5 using custom helpers with in-built helpers and no App_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an MVC 5 project using VB.NET and EF 6. I have added an EditorTemplates nuget package which relies upon Custom Global Helpers.

In C# I can merely add new helpers wherever as a `public static class`, then add the namespace to `~/Views/Web.config` and off I go. To the best of my knowledge C# and VB.NET differ here greatly.

After much battling with the compiler and Stack Overflow searching I found that I could get the custom helpers to work in views if placed them in the App_Code folder.

I used a Module with the `<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>` attribute applied to each method. Then added to `~/Views/Web.config` and the App_code folder and compile.

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Public Module HtmlHelpers
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function HelperName(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, hn As HelperName) As MvcHtmlString        
        Return MvcHtmlString.Create(hn.ToString())
    End Function
End Module
```

This allows me to use the new custom helpers, but completely blocks out all of the in-built html helpers like DisplayFor, EditorFor and ActionLink.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. There seems to be no documentation whatsoever about this online, apart from [confirming the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451287/razor-declarative-html-helpers/4453637#4453637), then ignoring it for over 5 years.

How can I use both? I'm at the end of my tether and losing faith in Microsoft's support/documentation.

Comment: Whoever downvoted and close-voted this question. Thankyou so much for providing some insight as to why this isn't a valid question, or why you feel it should be removed. Rather than further trying to prevent me from finding a solution without supplying a reason.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your helper first in its own library instead of App_Code? I my owner helpers written in VBnet and have not seen this issue. I however have my helpers in a separate project that I compile.

Comment: No I haven't tried this. Would I just add them to a seperate class library project, and then reference them from the solution and web.config? Is there anything I need to bear in mind other than that? Cheers, Matt.

Comment: I've managed to find a solution/work-around. I'm going to clean things up and find what exactly I've done to fix it, then I'll post the solution.

Comment: Yes you can just create a separate project to hold your helpers, compile, and then add the reference and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1. **Do not use App_Code.** Put the helpers elsewhere. I've put mine in ~/Helpers/
2. **Do not use namespaces.** This was probably my downfall, though cannot be sure without further testing.
3. **Add root project namespace to ~/Views/Web.config**

   ```
   <add namespace="MyProjectName" />
   ```

   **NOT**

   ```
   <add namespace="MyProjectName.Helpers" />
   <add namespace="HtmlHelpers" />
   <add namespace="OrAnythingLikeThis" />
   ```
4. **Ensure helpers are being compiled at build time** (Class.vb > Properties > Build Action: Compile)

I'm 99% sure that's it. I had issues with BootstrapEditorTemplates as they were C# and I'm working in VB.NET. To solve this I converted the helpers to VB.NET and placed them all in a single HtmlHelpers.vb file, in ~/Helpers/,  with the rest of my custom ones. Doing this probably wasn't all necessary; you could probably accomplish the same by just removing the namespace in the C# helper files, but I haven't tested.

If this doesn't work then give me a shout (on this question, not pm) and I'll come back and try to solve it.