# How to create a declarative HTML helper in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

my scenario:

I am finally getting around to creating my own blog, and I am trying to learn as much as possible with regards to MVC while doing so. I am trying to display my tags as a custom declarative helper in my "`PostView.cshtml`" file but my problem is that it isn't in the current context and I don't know how to make it so.

I have had a look at the following 2 questions on SO:

[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451287/razor-declarative-html-helpers) is for previous version of MVC (<= 4) and

[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505102/vb-net-mvc-5-use-custom-helpers-with-in-built-helpers-no-app-code) was answered by the guy who asked the question and isn't very explanatory.

I tried the above advice but with no success, hopefully someone can help me out. Here is my code:

**Tags.cshtml** (in ~/Views/Helpers/):

```
@helper Tags(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
ICollection<MyNamespace.Objects.Tag> tags)
{
    foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        <div class="tags-div">
            @MyNamespace.Extensions.ActionLinkExtensions.TagLink(htmlHelper, tag):
        </div>
    }
}
```

**ActionLinkExtensions.cs** (in ~/Extensions/ActionLinkExtensions/)

```
namespace MyNamespace.Extensions
{
    public static class ActionLinkExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString TagLink(this HtmlHelper helper, Tag tag)
        {
            return helper.ActionLink("", ""); //logic removed for simplicity
        }
    }
}
```

**PostView.cshtml** (in ~/Views/Shared/) //where i want to use my custom helper:

```
@model MyNamespace.Objects.Post
<!--extra html removed for simplicity-->
<div>
    <span>Tags:</span>@Tags(Html, Model.Tags) // '@Tags' doesn't exist in current context
</div>
```

I also tried adding namespaces to '~/Views/web.config':

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="MyNamespace" />
    <add namespace="MyNamespace.Extensions" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

My "full name" for my "Tag.cs" class is `MyNamespace.Objects.Tag` and "Post".cs" is `MyNamespace.Objects.Post`.

Any explanations and advice with an answer would be greatly appreciated too, thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to try use MVC3 way, I added the App_Code folder manually and followed steps from [**this great article**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor).
And it worked, I needed to restart Visual Studio for my Intellisense to work (which prolonged finding my solution).

I deleted the folder *'~/Views/Shared/'*

I Added a file `MyHelpers.cshtml` into the App_Code folder, inside the file I added my helper method:

```
@helper Tags(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    ICollection<MyNamespace.Objects.Tag> tags)
{
    foreach (var tag in tags)
    {
        <div class="tags-div">
            @MyNamespace.Extensions.ActionLinkExtensions.TagLink(htmlHelper, tag)
        </div>
    }
}
```

And called it in my `PostView.cshtml` like so:

```
@MyHelpers.Tags(Html, Model.Tags)
```

And Viola works as expected... hopefully this helps someone else who ends up in this situation...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the better and simpler way would be to define a display template for you Tags collection that would be placed in `~Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`:

```
@model ICollection<MyNamespace.Objects.Tag>

foreach (var tag in Model)
{
    <div class="tags-div">
        @MyNamespace.Extensions.ActionLinkExtensions.TagLink(htmlHelper, tag)
    </div>
}
```

In your `PostView.cshtml` you would then just write:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Tags)
```